# What do we call for the people who made a difference

Tags: terminology

I am looking for the exact term for the man who made a difference. 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "exact" is tough to pin down, without knowing the type of person or situation where it would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiomatically, people like this are called...

> [**Movers and shakers**](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/movers-and-shakers.html) - *People of energetic demeanour, who initiate change and influence events.*

For an adjectival form, it's common to say they're ***influential*** people *(people of influence)*.

Comment: Can also be called `extraordinary`?

Comment: Lots of *extraordinary people* don't actually influence things much on the broader scale (idiot savants, people with missing or extra limbs, etc.).

Comment: Nowadays you see "change makers" a lot.

Comment: @user3169: That's a catchy title for politicians, pressure groups, and arts council funding committees, but for the more general context I think it's [pretty obviously an (ephemeral?) "also-ran".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=change+makers%2Cmovers+and+shakers&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchange%20makers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmovers%20and%20shakers%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2):

As @user3169 commented, there could be many depending on context, but you could consider using [**game changer**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/game-changer) which means:

> a person or thing that dramatically changes the course, strategy,
>   character, etc., of something

[Dictionary.com]